# Peugeot 307 cranks but won't run

Tags: peugeot, cranks-wont-run

I have a Peugeot 307 1.4 HDI (year 2004, Europe) that started this morning but right now it doesn't want to start. What do I mean by that? Well, by turning the key the engine cranks but it doesn't  run so I can keep doing this until the battery voltage goes under 11V.

What I've checked so far:

- I have enough fuel
- the battery has enough voltage to crank the engine (if not I recharge it until the voltage > 12.7V)
- all the fuse are working (none are blown)
- the fuel pump located on the tank works (by turning the engine I see some fuel flowing through the transparent fuel line)
- I saw some air (thought that there might be some air) on the fuel line so I bled the air from the fuel line manually by using the fuel line (rubber) pump; I mean I pressed that pump until I saw no bubble flowing through the transparent fuel line.

My feeling is that the problem is due to air trapped in fuel line which locks the fuel line preventing the normal supply of fuel into cylinder.

I would appreciate some advise / hints.

Note: I'm not a mechanic but I like to fix the car when I can.

Comment: This is a diesel, correct? Two questions: Is there a manual primer for the fuel system? Have you checked fuses? I'd bet your Peugeot has two fuel pumps ... a low pressure (to get the fuel from the pump to the engine) and a high pressure (to inject it into the engine). Just because you have fuel flow to the engine, doesn't mean the injector pump is working. Check the fuses and if that doesn't pan out, I'd suggest you may have a high-pressure pump issue.

Comment: If the diesel manual primer is that manual rubber pump connected to the fuel line then the answer is yes, I've already mentioned that. I've checked all fuses, as I've already mentioned that in my question :-)

Answer (score 4):

OK, so I've fixed it.

After posting my question here and since my feeling was that the problem seems to be related to some air bubbles in the fuel system, I've decided to take out the fuel filter, drain all the diesel fuel, fill it manually (by using 10ml syringe since I hadn't a manual pump) with diesel and mount it back.

I've tried to start the engine but didn't work. I've tried few more times and finally it started but also it threw some smoke (not too much though) somewhere behind the engine (it was hard to notice that, however I thought it was worth to mention this).

Since I am not a mechanic and never experienced this before it is hard to tell what was the real cause for sure. Since the fix works I assume that my initial guess is confirmed.

I just want to mention something I've learned on the process and which might help others newbies like me to fix their cars. An internal combustion engine needs 4 different things to run:

- the fuel (check the fuel system: the low pressure fuel tank pump, the fuel line, the fuel filter, the high pressure injector fuel pump)
- the air (check your car air system, including some air-related sensors like intake air sensor, O2 sensor, etc)
- the spark/ignition (check the spark plugs, some sensors)
- the compression (engine internal, if you are newbie then this should be the last item to be checked, preferably by a mechanic).

Since all these systems are electrical connected make sure all fuses work.

Comment: Excellent work; I'm glad your car is running again.   Not in every case will a vehicle have ignition parts (spark plugs) - which I am fairly confident is true with your 307.